# TensorFlowLite error interpreter.set_tensor()

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tensorflow-lite

My keras model:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(keras.layers.InputLayer(input_shape=(1134,), dtype='float64'))
model.add(Dense(1024, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(512, activation='relu'))
model.add(keras.layers.Dropout(0.35))
model.add(Dense(3, activation='softmax'))
```

After training, i convert model to tflite

```
converter = tf.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_keras_model(model)
converter.target_spec.supported_ops = [tf.lite.OpsSet.SELECT_TF_OPS] <-- without this I will get an error
tflite_model = converter.convert()

with open('model.tflite', 'wb') as f:
  f.write(tflite_model)
```

Then i want to test model:

````
interpreter = tf.lite.Interpreter(model_path="/content/model.tflite")
interpreter.allocate_tensors()
input_details = interpreter.get_input_details()
output_details = interpreter.get_output_details()

input_shape = input_details[0]['shape']
inp = np.expand_dims(X[0], axis=0)
interpreter.set_tensor(input_details[0]['index'], inp) <-- in this line i get error```

Error:
````

ValueError: Cannot set tensor: Got value of type NOTYPE but expected type FLOAT64 for input 0, name: input_1 ```

Comment: Please clarify what is inside of `X[0]`

Comment: np.array consist of 1134 np.float64 numbers

Comment: Just in case check out `inp` to make sure it has floats inside. Also  what is yours `input_shape `?

Comment: Inside the inp are indeed float64, I checked this. input_shape based on the documentation is - Shape tuple (not including the batch axis), or TensorShape instance (not including the batch axis).

Comment: Then everything should work .) But `set_tensor()` makes a copy of data, maybe you have some issues during this. Try to use [tensor](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/lite/Interpreter#tensor) strategy.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
interpreter = tf.lite.Interpreter(model_path="/content/model.tflite")
interpreter.allocate_tensors()
input_details = interpreter.get_input_details()
output_details = interpreter.get_output_details()

input_shape = input_details[0]['shape']
inp = np.expand_dims(X[0], axis=0)

inp = inp.astype(np.float64) # This was missing

interpreter.set_tensor(input_details[0]['index'], inp)
```

Comment: Can you create and end-to-end notebook with your code so I can debug it? In Google colab, create a new notebook and share the link here: https://colab.sandbox.google.com/notebooks/intro.ipynb#recent=true

Comment: https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1-WxmYfn1ud5NXpcSaN296TiYfLo1nrLO?usp=sharing

Comment: raw_data.txt file https://drive.google.com/file/d/1MvOVI_6m33uDBfC-pdehwcmbin5_0VKF/view?usp=sharing